# ffmpeg: trsfer a h264 video to a series of jpg failed

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, h.264, decoding

me and a partner are trying to transfer a h264 video to a series of images using ffmpeg with the following command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.h264 -qscale:v 2 output_%03d.jpg
```

The input.h264 can be played perfectly on vlc, but the images generated by ffmpeg are just all black. The message in the console are below:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.2-2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] error while decoding MB 54 2, bytestream -16
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] error while decoding MB 2 9, bytestream 6907
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] concealing 1275 DC, 1275 AC, 1275 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] error while decoding MB 27 0, bytestream 5564
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] deblocking filter parameters 7 13 out of range
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] concealing 1440 DC, 1440 AC, 1440 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] deblocking filter parameters 7 -14 out of range
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] concealing 1387 DC, 1387 AC, 1387 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] deblocking filter parameters -7 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] concealing 1413 DC, 1413 AC, 1413 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] error while decoding MB 9 0, bytestream 6647
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] concealing 1186 DC, 1186 AC, 1186 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] error while decoding MB 16 9, bytestream 6182
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] error while decoding MB 6 18, bytestream 7043
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afd9e0] concealing 1440 DC, 1440 AC, 1440 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2afc8c0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, h264, from 'temp_file.h264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 1280x720, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1200k tbn, 59.94 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b2f900] error while decoding MB 54 2, bytestream -16
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b2f900] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b2f900] error while decoding MB 2 9, bytestream 6907
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b2f900] concealing 1275 DC, 1275 AC, 1275 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b01080] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b01080] error while decoding MB 27 0, bytestream 5564
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b01080] deblocking filter parameters 7 13 out of range
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b01080] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b01080] concealing 1440 DC, 1440 AC, 1440 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c49240] deblocking filter parameters 7 -14 out of range
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c49240] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c49240] concealing 1387 DC, 1387 AC, 1387 MV errors in P frame
Output #0, image2, to 'output_%03d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b7fec0] deblocking filter parameters -7 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b7fec0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b7fec0] concealing 1413 DC, 1413 AC, 1413 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c15240] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c15240] error while decoding MB 9 0, bytestream 6647
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c15240] concealing 1186 DC, 1186 AC, 1186 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c315a0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c315a0] error while decoding MB 16 9, bytestream 6182
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c315a0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c315a0] error while decoding MB 6 18, bytestream 7043
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c315a0] concealing 1440 DC, 1440 AC, 1440 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c447a0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c447a0] error while decoding MB 12 9, bytestream 6863
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c447a0] concealing 1342 DC, 1342 AC, 1342 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2bb9180] top block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0x562ab2bb9180] error while decoding MB 29 18, bytestream 6611
[h264 @ 0x562ab2bb9180] concealing 1405 DC, 1405 AC, 1405 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2bd54e0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0x562ab2bd54e0] error while decoding MB 25 9, bytestream 6051
[h264 @ 0x562ab2bd54e0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2bd54e0] error while decoding MB 70 18, bytestream 5088
[h264 @ 0x562ab2bd54e0] concealing 1419 DC, 1419 AC, 1419 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2bf1840] top block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0x562ab2bf1840] error while decoding MB 14 9, bytestream 6071
[h264 @ 0x562ab2bf1840] deblocking filter parameters -9 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x562ab2bf1840] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x562ab2bf1840] concealing 1440 DC, 1440 AC, 1440 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab318e0a0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab318e0a0] error while decoding MB 54 9, bytestream 4422
[h264 @ 0x562ab318e0a0] concealing 1256 DC, 1256 AC, 1256 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab31aa020] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab31aa020] error while decoding MB 22 9, bytestream 5862
[h264 @ 0x562ab31aa020] concealing 1335 DC, 1335 AC, 1335 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2d5a8c0] deblocking filter parameters 7 -4 out of range
[h264 @ 0x562ab2d5a8c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x562ab2d5a8c0] concealing 1430 DC, 1430 AC, 1430 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b2f900] concealing 1319 DC, 1319 AC, 1319 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b01080] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b01080] error while decoding MB 16 9, bytestream 6218
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b01080] concealing 1416 DC, 1416 AC, 1416 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c49240] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c49240] error while decoding MB 12 0, bytestream 6854
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c49240] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c49240] error while decoding MB 2 9, bytestream 7092
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c49240] concealing 1440 DC, 1440 AC, 1440 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b7fec0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b7fec0] error while decoding MB 59 0, bytestream 4955
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b7fec0] deblocking filter parameters 7 15 out of range
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b7fec0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x562ab2b7fec0] concealing 1430 DC, 1430 AC, 1430 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c15240] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c15240] error while decoding MB 34 0, bytestream 5338
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c15240] deblocking filter parameters 7 13 out of range
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c15240] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c15240] concealing 1440 DC, 1440 AC, 1440 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c315a0] concealing 1344 DC, 1344 AC, 1344 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c447a0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c447a0] error while decoding MB 49 9, bytestream 4992
[h264 @ 0x562ab2c447a0] concealing 1228 DC, 1228 AC, 1228 MV errors in P frame
frame=   21 fps=0.0 q=2.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.70 bitrate=N/A speed=1.31x    
video:601kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

However, this command works perfectly fine on random h264 videoes on the internet, so I guess there may be something wrong with our h264 video, but the weird thing is that it can be played by vlc player just fine...

Any idea what the problem can be? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beginning of your file seems to be broken.  How was it generated? Try

```
ffplay -flags output_corrupt input.h264
```

See also this [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824970/h264-extracting-frames-works-only-on-certain-operating-system-ffmpeg-version).